# select row with same entry in different columns

Tags: mysql

Suppose you have a table User table and there are two different columns user_name and email_id. Now I need to get all those entries whose user_name and email_id is same/different.

Comment: Suppose we have a table User and I need 1 and 3 in this.
**User**

id | user_name      | email_id      
---|----------------      |--------------- 
1  | john@gmail.com | john@gmail.com
2  | rema           | rema@gmail.com 
3  | aksh@gmail.com | aksh@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM User
WHERE user_name = email_id    -- use user_name <> email_id to get entries
                              -- which do not match
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM `User` where user_name= email_id